# HTML Agility Pack Conversion to XML <script> corruption

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml, html-agility-pack

I've got an HTML file with a `<script>` in it:

```
<html>
   <script type="application/custom+xml">
   <my><xml><goes><here/></goes></xml></my>
   </script>
</html>
```

I parse it with HTML Agility Pack and then convert it to XML.

```
HtmlDocument html;
html.OptionOutputAsXml = true;
html.Save(stream);
...
XDocument xml = XDocument.Load(stream);
```

I then want to use LINQ-to-XML to look at the contents of the `script` tag which should contain my XML as CDATA. But HTML Agility Pack messes it up somehow and I end up with this escaped XML:

```
<html>
<script type="application/custom+xml">
//<![CDATA[
&lt;my&gt;&lt;xml&gt;&lt;goes&gt;&lt;here/&gt;&lt;/goes&gt;&lt;/xml&gt;&lt;/my&gt;
//]]>//
</script>
</html>
```

Does anyone know how I can tell HTML Agility Pack not to escape the contents of the `script` tag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's rather easy, by default the AgilityPack is set to treat script tags content as CData, this is done in the static constructor of the HtmlNode class like so:

```
ElementsFlags.Add("script", HtmlElementFlag.CData);
```

To change this one doesn't have to modify the AgilityPack, all that's needed is one thing before your code, or just once when your program starts

```
HtmlNode.ElementsFlags.Remove("script");
```

Just add that before your code, like that it works for me.