# How I can get the string result of a view passing it the model in a controller action in Asp.net MVC

Tags: xml, asp.net-mvc

I need to load the resultant string from an specific view for load it in an XmlDocument object in a controller action for make other operations with it.

I want to use that view as a Template, its generates SVG images.

Once I have the result I need to passed as an XMLDocument to a third party dll that takes the XMLDocument and convert it into a bitmap image

How you can do that? It supposed to be a simple operation but I didnt find a clue how to do it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: views have no `result`, can you elaborate?

Comment: Your question is not clear enough. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I don't really undertsand that you want to achieve. Do you want to generate XML from a view and save its result in a file ?

Comment: I updated my question to clarify that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question really is not clear.

If you want to get rendered html as string you can get the string output of the View using the following extension method:

```cs
public static string RenderPartialView(this Controller controller, string viewName, object model)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(viewName))
        viewName = controller.ControllerContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");

    controller.ViewData.Model = model;
    using (var sw = new StringWriter())
    {
        ViewEngineResult viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(controller.ControllerContext, viewName);
        var viewContext = new ViewContext(controller.ControllerContext, viewResult.View, controller.ViewData, controller.TempData, sw);
        viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);

        return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
    }
}
```

Use it like this (in the code for the Action):

```cs
var model = [whatever is the model that is used by the view]
var renderedView = this.RenderPartialView("Path to the view", model);
```

Then you can parse this string into document using [Html Agility Pack](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/). You can find out how to do it in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14159028/html-agility-pack-conversion-to-xml-script-corruption).